# Service Fabric Cluster Arm template deploy error

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am using vsts release to deploy my arm template. The template is a 2 node type service fabric cluster, with all the required things attached. I had an issue when the scale sets auto-scaling would scale the number of VMs down, and the service would lose quorum because the scale set doesn't seem to tell the cluster scaling is about to happen, so I thought changing the durability level from bronze to silver might help. That was a mistake, as even though the documentation says silver is available, when you create a cluster in the azure portal, only bronze and gold are available. Gold is not an option, as it forces the VM size to be D15_V2 or G5, which is crazy money. So back to bronze.

But now, my template won't deploy... The cluster resource itself is stuck deploying. At time of writing, it has been going almost 2 hours, which in my experience, is unprecedented. I have tried this multiple times, and it gets stuck here repeatedly.

The information I'm getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "An error occurred.",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

As you can see, very helpful!

The activity log isn't much better. It merely says the write cluster operation has failed. Is there a way to get more detailed diagnostics? Any ideas are really appreciated as there are just no clues as to what is failing.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried deploying it from Visual Studio to see if it can be deployed successfully?

Comment: I had the same error when deploying from Visual Studio. However! somewhere along the way, another change to the template was made. Some parameters were moved to be variables, along with all references to those params also being edited. After reverting this change, the error is gone. I don't know why this broke it. The template was valid, and all required values were present and being used. A bit of a weird one.

Comment: did you solve this? you can actually get a more detailed error

Comment: no idea I'm afraid, it was a while ago. I would wager it was some kind of error within the template that was fixed when the other changes were made... should I resolve this question somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a variable called "system.debug" with the value "true" to get verbose logging information after a release.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually already have this variable set...

Comment: Ok, well from VSTS there is unfortunately no other option to get more detailed diagnostics. I don't know what you have tried to see in Azure. You can select the resourcegroup where you deploy to and click on the link Last Deployment. An alternative is to select the Activity log in the portal (on the resourcegroup or in the menu). I'm afraid this will not show you more information...